# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function When using Angular Google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-material

I'm trying using agm for my project to auto compete the form fields. I just installed using the command `npm install @agm/core` and in `app.module` i added the `AgmCoreModule` in imports. i didn't use any code related to agm, saved the project and ran `ng serve` and getting this error.

```
agm-core.js:4538 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at agm-core.js:4538
at Module.../../node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js (agm-core.js:4544)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

I have no idea what this means.Please tell me what's the problem.
Here is my `package.json` file dependencies and dev dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"and": "0.0.3",
"angular-mgl-timeline": "^0.3.2",
"angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^10.2.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"},
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
"@angular/cli": "^7.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.2.2"}
```

Everything works fine if i remove the import but if i add again error stop the project from running.

Comment: This might be something to do with your app.module.ts file; did you declare the module in there?

Comment: how do you import the module? make sure to call forRoot like so: AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'yourKey',
      libraries: ['places']
    }),

Comment: just imported agm module in app.module.ts nothing else

Comment: @Hoff that's exactly what i did. i just imported and put api key and places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Edit your app.module.ts
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  // Add this also
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'your key',
      libraries: ['places'] 
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: I did exactly as i was told to do.

Comment: Which version of AGM are using??  
You should try to use  this "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7"

Comment: remove your current version: npm uninstall @agm/core
then install this version: npm i @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7 --save

Comment: i'm using the latest version

Comment: Installing beta version gives this error :ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\CustomerRegistration\customer-registration\node_modules\@agm\core\fesm5\agm-core.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (E:\CustomerRegistration\customer-registration\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFile(E:\CustomerRegistration\customer-registration\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)

Comment: Which version are you using?? Because it is not in your package.json file (Uploaded by you in question)

Comment: installed beta version as you mentioned and Problem solved ! Thank you

Answer (score 22):

**Or Change your Agm Version to**

remove your current version:

**npm uninstall @agm/core**

then install this version:

**npm i @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7 --save**

Comment: Thanks that did work , just did `npm i @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7 --save`

Comment: error remove but nothing showing on browser Amit Kumar

Comment: agm-map {
  height: 300px;
}    // Add height to agm map

Comment: @AmitSharma you are accurate brother!

Answer (score 7):

Version 1.1.0 of AGM module was released yesterday and I believe it uses Angular 8. We had to revert back to 1.0.0 to jive with Angular 7.

Answer (score 4):

I am developing in angular 7 and using agm module in app.
by mistake i just reinstall agm core module.
when installation was complete it gave me same error.
agm version "^1.1.0" is not compatible with angular 7.
fix was i did just @agm/core:"^1.1.0" to "1.0.0" in package.json

Answer (score 4):

Or Change your Agm Version to

remove your current version:

`npm uninstall @agm/core`

then install this version:

`npm i @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7 --save`

That's perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

We had to revert back to 1.0.0 to jive with Angular 7.

Or Change your Agm Version to

remove your current version:

npm uninstall @agm/core

then install this version:

npm i @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.7 --save